# Derive the value of $z$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

So I was trying to derive but got stuck on how to acquire the value of $z$.

Is it possible to obtain the value of $z$ manually? I can't seem to figure it out. I know the RHS could be raised to $(z-1)+z$ however I have problem with the $z/c$.
$$
x = \left( {\frac{z}{c}} \right)\left( {\frac{v}{c}} \right)^{z - 1} e^{ - \left( {\frac{v}{c}} \right)^z }  \to \ln x = \ln\left( {\frac{z}{c}} \right) +  (z-1)\ln\left( {\frac{v}{c}} \right)  - \left( {\frac{v}{c}} \right)^z 
$$

So, $$\ln(z) - \ln(c) +  (z-1)\ln\left( {\frac{v}{c}} \right)  - \left( {\frac{v}{c}} \right)^z $$

Comment: Are you sure you took the logarithm correctly?

Comment: I don't think it's possible to solve for $z$, unless you use Lamber's W function ...

Comment: @Gary what do you mean? so logarithm should still stay with the first two. but wouldn't that be distributive? oh yea sorry i forgot it was supposed to be addition

Comment: I mean, you have to take the $\ln$ of the first two factors $(z/c)$ and $(v/c)^{z-1}$ as well.

Comment: @Gary thank you for pointing it out. however from the above i know i can still do the 

$(z-1) ln(v) - ln(c)$ but how about the third one I already used ln and it is raised in z